# Problema setando CSS dentro do 'style'

Tags: html, css

Estou enfrentando um problema. Desejo colocar todo o meu CSS dentro da tag Style como mostra meu código a seguir:

```
<style>
    input[data-column="1"] { display: none; }
    input[data-column="2"] { display: none; }
    .editCancelar { margin-left:-2px;cursor:pointer; display:none }
    .editConcluir { margin-left:0px;cursor:pointer; display:none }
    .sgr_hidden { display:none }
    .bradC { color: White!important }
</style>
```

Porém a classe .bradC não está atribuindo seu estilo aos objetos. Só funciona se eu setar a propriedade style dentro do objeto html, como fiz a seguir:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" style="padding-top: 17px; margin-left: 15px">
    <li><a class="bradC" href="javascript:navegacao( 'mnManutencao', 'mnPrincipal' )">Início</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:navegacao( 'mnPrincipal', 'mnManutencao' )" class="bradC">Manutenção</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:navegacao( 'mnPrincipal', 'mnManUnidadeGerencial' )" class="bradC" >Unidade Gerencial e Equipe</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="bradC">Cadastro Classificação</a></li>
</ol>
```

**Informação adicional:**

Ao inspecionar o elemento vejo que o color do elemento está vindo de um arquivo CSS que definiu a cor para todos os elementos "a.bradC:link, a.bradC:visited".

Esse arquivo CSS carrega na página, e a minha tag "style" da página com o css definido fica abaixo dele.

**Pergunta:**

Como funciona a atribuição do CSS nesse caso? Como fazer com que eu possa organizar tudo dentro do style da página, podendo retirar a propriedade style do meu elemento? Não tenho como trocar a ordem da posição do arquivo CSS com o "style" pois ele vem de uma master page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema pode ser o elemento ter um CSS defenido para `a.bradC:link` e você está a tentar forçar a cor para `a.bradC`.

Nesse caso sem o `:link` como não é exatamente a mesma regra, ele pode não sobrepôr. Porém acho que a haver esse comportamento será diferente em browsers diferentes. Ele devia sobrepôr.

Tente isso:

```
a.bradC:link, a.bradC:visited { color: White!important }
```

Porém nos browsers que experimentei consigo sobrepor a cor da maneira esperada. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2XTy/)